# MongoDb find collection document based on timestamp

Tags: php, python, mongodb, find, timestamp

I have user profile data as:

```
    {u'DOB': None,
    u'_id': ObjectId('5906f3b.....'),
    u'active': 0,
    u'bfunc': 0,
    u'city': None,
    u'contact': u'',
```

> u'created': 1493627839,

```
    u'email': u'mymail@demo.c
    u'facebook_id': u'',
    u'fburl': None,
    u'firstname': u'',
    u'gender': None,
    u'group_id': None}
```

I want to find all data between last 4 hrs based on  `created` field.

Current `created value` is `1493627839` which is `2017-05-01 14:07:19`

I want to find `lessthan` current time and `greaterthan` last 4 hrs.
How could i find value based on datetime.

Should i convert current time into `timestamp` then find or something else?

I did this but it returned 0 as my values stored in `timestamp` format.

```
   value = []
    cursor = collection.find({
        'created': {
            "$gte": datetime.datetime.now(),
            "$lt": datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        }
    })
```

how could i query it.

Note: I am storing values in `php` but this query is fired in 'python 2.7'.

Edit:

```
   value = []
    cursor = collection.find({
        'created': {
            "$lt": datetime.datetime.now(),
            "$gte": datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        }
    })
```

but still find query is empty

Comment: what is output of datetime.timedelta(days=5) ?

Comment: @Love-Kesh if value of `datetime.datetime.now(),`  is 2017-05-01 14:07:19 then value of `datetime.timedelta(days=5) ` 2017-04-30 17:00:25.097000

Answer (score 1):

**You are using opposite condition , use as follow**

```
timenow=datetime.datetime.now();
ltunix = timenow.strftime('%s');  //convert to timestamp

gteTime= timenow- datetime.timedelta(hours=4);
getTimeUnix=gteTime.strftime('%s');  //convert to timestamp

cursor = collection.find({
            'created': {
                "$lt": ltunix,
                "$gte": getTimeUnix
            }
        })
```

Comment: thnkx for correction but it still showing nothing in find.

Comment: is your query working without any condition , like find() ?

Comment: yes...it shows all values... I also copied output of find({}) up.

Comment: Now check for only $lt , then only $gte condition , and see output one by one. Also increase gte time difference like datetime.timedelta(days=5) for testing

Comment: still empty list... `[]` checked both $lt and $gte

Comment: getting error... `ValueError: Invalid format string`

Comment: try this import date_converter;      

timestamp = date_converter.date_to_timestamp(d)

Comment: `ImportError: No module named date_converter` try to install it but error `  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement date_converter (from v
ersions: )
No matching distribution found for date_converter
`

Comment: Try like this  datetime.datetime.strptime( "04:05:2017", '%H:%M:%S').time() or fire a separate question on stack overflow for convert to timestamp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143500/discussion-between-vivek-and-love-kesh).

Comment: i converted into timestamp