# how to convert todays datetime into timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I am tryng to convert date-time into string.

I am searching answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803400/mongodb-find-collection-document-based-on-timestamp/43803858?noredirect=1#comment74647015_43803858)

when i do this

```
time.mktime(time.strptime('2017-05-01 14:07:19',  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

i am able convert datetime into time-stamp but I want to concert today's date into time-stamp like this:

```
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
//timenow = 2017-05-01 14:07:19
time.mktime(time.strptime(timenow,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

then it throws error `TypeError: expected string or buffer` even i tried like

```
 time.mktime(time.strptime(str(timenow),  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

then it throws `ValueError: unconverted data remains: .067000`

How could i convert todays datetime into `timestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print(now.timestamp())
```

Comment: sure. just convert it to int. `print(int(now.timestamp()))`

Comment: ohh..its easy thnkx a lot I tried earlier but it throws error but now its format converted.

Comment: Hey I have another question and this is part of that .... could u just look at this plz... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803400/mongodb-find-collection-document-based-on-timestamp/43803858?noredirect=1#comment74647015_43803858)